# Selecting the min num for each value of a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that is like this:

```
col1       col2       num
a        <string1>     5
a        <string2>     10
a        <string3>     0
a        <string4>     7
b        <string1>     6
b        <string2>     3
b        <string3>     20
b        <string4>     1
```

I want to select the min num for each value of col1 (or eventually col2), so the desired output would be:

```
col1       col2        num
a        <string3>     0
b        <string4>     1
```

How can I achieve this? I'm trying to do this in BigQuery.

Comment: BigQuery or Postgres? Please adjust the tag with the description of the question (or the other way around...).

Comment: Its bigquery. I got the the wrong. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Postgres (as tagged), you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (col1) t.*
from mytable t
order by col1, num
```

In BigQuery (as mentionned in the question), you can do this with arrays:

```
select array_agg(t order by num limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from mytable t
group by col1
```

Comment: Thank you both! This actually worked. One last thing, I added `where num<=10` and then `order by col.num`, where `col` is the alias I gave to the `array_agg(t order by num limit 1)[offset(0)].*`. Why in the `where` clause I can just put `num` there and in the `order by` clause I need to add `col.`?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select as value array_agg(t order by num limit 1)[offset(0)]
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by col1
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  select 'a' col1, '<string1>' col2, 5 num union all
  select 'a', '<string2>', 10 union all
  select 'a', '<string3>', 0 union all
  select 'a', '<string4>', 7 union all
  select 'b', '<string1>', 6 union all
  select 'b', '<string2>', 3 union all
  select 'b', '<string3>', 20 union all
  select 'b', '<string4>', 1 
)
select as value array_agg(t order by num limit 1)[offset(0)]
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by col1
```

the output is

[image]